# Changing the default selection of a dropdown option in the Search function

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I'm new to Drupal and am stuck trying to fix the default option on a dropdown Taxonomy filter on my Custom Search box. See it in the sidebar at [artnotapart.com](http://artnotapart.com/)

The Year taxonomy is defaulting to 2015 and I can't find a setting to change it. It doesn't default to 2015 when I use a checkbox to display the options.

I've been through a lot of the core files (not sure if I've been through the right ones) but can't see a hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() which I think are they ways one would implement this feature.

Very stuck at the moment, any suggestions?